# NSOperationQueue waitUntillAllOperationsAreFinished blocks operations

Tags: cocoa, nsthread, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I've created my own NSOperation subclass and now I want some of its instances to run in parallel. As it's a concurrent operation I've overwritten

```
- (void)start {
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
    isExecuting = YES;
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];

    error=NO;
    startedSection=NO;

    // start the task
    [task launch];
}

- (BOOL)isConcurrent {
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)isExecuting {
    return isExecuting;
}

- (BOOL)isFinished {
    return isFinished;
}
```

and the following code is executed when the operation finishes:

```
[self willChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
[self willChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
isExecuting = NO;
isFinished = YES;
[self didChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
[self didChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
```

When I add `[myQueue waitUntillAllOperationsAreFinished]` after having added the operations to `myQueue` none of the operations even starts! When I remove the `[myQueue waitUntillAllOperationsAreFinished]` I get what I want, except for the fact that this could lead to some errors because of the main thread interfering with these operations ...

Answer (score 0):

How is the concurrency of the operations implemented? I suspect you're dispatching things to the main thread and you're also blocking in the main thread in `-waitUntillAllOperationsAreFinished`. That will, of course, deadlock.

Comment: Actually I didn't implement anything ... Shouldn't the operation run on a new thread different from the main one?

Comment: You overrode `-isConcurrent` to return `YES`. That means *you* are taking responsibility for running it concurrently. You should only do that if you have special requirements. The terminology is somewhat confusing. Think of it more as concurrent == asynchronous, non-concurrent == synchronous. The "easy" path is to leave your operations as non-concurrent / synchronous. In that case, the operation *queue* will arrange to invoke the operation on a thread that the queue manages. The operation will be run concurrent with other operations, but synchronous from the point of view of the queue.

Comment: The problem is that my operation is running an NSTask which is run asynchronously in order to get its output ...

Comment: So why did you say you didn't implement anything? Anyway, show your `-start` method. Also, probably a good idea to log the value from `+[NSThread isMainThread]` and/or `+[NSThread currentThread]` within it and within the waiting thread. I suspect the queue is starting your op on the thread where you queued it. That would mean that `NSTask` is dependent on that thread's run loop. If you're then blocking that thread in `-waitUntillAllOperationsAreFinished`, you'd prevent receipt of task termination notifications and background reads of the output.

Comment: I just did some logging ... the thread from which I execute `-waitUntillAllOperationsAreFinished` has a different address from the threads of the operations themselves, which aren't run in the main thread (`[NSThread isMainThread]` returns false.

Comment: So the `-start` method of your operation is being invoked? I assume so, since that's where you would have logged the thread. That suggests nothing is preventing the operations from running. You're sure that `task` is non-`nil`? Try to get a backtrace of all threads. You can do that from a debugger (e.g. `thread apply all bt` in gdb) or by sampling the process. See which ones might be mutually blocked on the other. By the way, I see that you misspelled `-waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished` (and I copied you). I assume that's just a typo in your post and not your actual code, right?

Comment: The code just does what it's supposed to do when I remove the `-waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished` (sorry, I misspelled it). As soon as I add this line the program hangs ...